# PERL syntax error near "= ) "

Tags: perl

I have found this [example](https://www.dinotools.de/2008/11/24/einzelne-tracks-aus-gpx-dateien-extrahieren/) but I get this error:

> syntax error at ./test.pl line 11, near "= ) " Execution of ./test.pl
>   aborted due to compilation errors.

Line 11: `while($line = ) {`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author of the script didn't prepare the script to be included in an HTML. The actual code was

```
while ($line = <INFILE>) {
```

See [readline](http://p3rl.org/readline) for details.